# Foreign text on English website

Tags: seo, meta-tags, multilingual, language

We decided to add translation links in our website for other languages. We have added 3 links for that:

> English | සිංහල | தமிழ்

My problem is that we have added meta tag saying that this page is in English and we cannot remove that meta tag as it is in the home page. I want to know that if I have these two foreign words in the site, will it affect to the SEO. Earlier adding some foreign content somehow resulted the low site rank. So I want to know that if this is the cause of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [use the `lang` attribute (e.g., on the `html` element)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/737/content-languages/2510/base-document-language#t=201608260844467955868) to declare the language, not a meta tag.

This allows you to overwrite the language declaration for other parts on the page (note the `lang` attributes in my [example markup for a language switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157416/1591669)).

Anyway, having a few words in a different language shouldn’t affect your SEO at all, whether you use `lang` or not.